# How to Save Contacts in phone using Qr code data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I want to save the Contacts numbers in my phone using QR code data in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts) for managing user contact book on Android & iOS and [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) or any other with qr scanning ability.

First create a template for qr information. [Flutter contacts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts) lets you save with vCard format which would be very useful, or just have contact name & number raw in qr data.

Once you have consistent formatting of qr data, after user scans code, pass data inside it to a new contact:

```
 final newContact =  Contact()
    ..name.first = 'John' //<- value from qr code
    ..name.last = 'Smith' //<- value from qr code
    ..phones = [Phone('555-123-4567')]; //<- value from qr code
  

    await newContact.insert();
```

More information available in package descriptions.

Comment: I tried this method but not getting output. when I Scan  QR code I'm getting output Details is in Text format but I want Direct import details as a contacts to my Phone device